# How to catch enter keypress on textarea but not shift+enter?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm doing it for texarea. A function should be called when the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but nothing should be done when <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> be pressed.

I try to simulate here a feature that many IM communicators have: sending a message on <kbd>Enter</kbd> but also adding multiple lines using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Are you using some javascript library such as jquery?

Comment: I must ask - why you try not to?

It today's world of compatibility, how are you accounting for each browser? 

Unless it's performance you're worried about, to which I guess you could pick and choose..

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar For example when developing Opera plugin using jquery means problems.

Comment: Ah, if it's for pluggin dev, it would make perfect sense to use Vanilla JS!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Test for the enter keycode (13) and if shift key was pressed.

```
...onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
//      if (e.shiftKey === true)
        if (e.shiftKey)  // thruthy
        {
            // new line
        }
        else
        {
            // run your function
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Accept all truthy values of `e.shiftKey`

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but why do you return false at the end of the if?

Comment: @Salmonface in browser event listeners, if you return false in the callback you prevent the default action. Hitting `enter` in a form with a submit button sends the form by default, but if you return false, it won't be sent. Note: you have to use `keydown` event to be able to prevent default key actions.

Comment: I had to use "==" instead of "==="

Comment: What's wrong with just `if (e.shiftKey)`? It's a boolean property.

Comment: @StefanReich it's probably good that way as well.

Comment: Is anybody tried in Safari?

Answer (score 2):

```
element.onkeydown = function(o) {
  o = o || event;
  if (o.shiftKey && o.keyCode == 13) {
    /* shift + enter pressed */
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using propper formatting for better readability?

Comment: @Stophface - Not sure why I formatted the way I did - it's a very old answer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a keydown event as well to check for the SHIFT key, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at the shiftKey property of the event object which will tell you if shift was held while the key was pressed.