# How can I detect shift + key down in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to catch enter keypress on textarea but not shift+enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178431/how-to-catch-enter-keypress-on-textarea-but-not-shiftenter)

How can I detect shift + key down in JavaScript?

Comment: You could've used those extra words to tell everyone what you have tried already. This answers your question, by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178431/how-to-catch-enter-keypress-on-textarea-but-not-shiftenter

Comment: oh well... for what it's worth: http://jsfiddle.net/3M6Xt/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
var onkeydown = (function (ev) {
  var key;
  var isShift;
  if (window.event) {
    key = window.event.keyCode;
    isShift = !!window.event.shiftKey; // typecast to boolean
  } else {
    key = ev.which;
    isShift = !!ev.shiftKey;
  }
  if ( isShift ) {
    switch (key) {
      case 16: // ignore shift key
        break;
      default:
        alert(key);
        // do stuff here?
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: All of this code is not needed (anymore). Please see the other answer.

Answer (score 206):

`event.shiftKey` is a boolean. `true` if the Shift key is being pressed, `false` if not. `altKey` and `ctrlKey` work the same way.

So basically you just need to detect the keydown as normal with `onkeydown`, and check those properties as needed.

Comment: I think this one is more informative than the selected answer, as it actually describes the behavior of the proper functionality, whereas the OA just presents a bunch of browser hacks for making sure this functionality works.

Comment: people should use event.key or event.code, beware of deprecation

Comment: what exactly is deprecated @AkinHwan can you give us reference!?