# Detecting key press sequence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have above script, **[CheckFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xstBM/)** or below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check(e){
        var text = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
                 
         switch(text){
         case 81:
            text = '&#4632;';
            break;
        case 87:
            text = '&#4633;';
            break;
        case 69:
            text = '&#4634;';
            break;
        case 82:
            text = '&#4635;';
            break;
        case 84:
            text = '&#4636;';
            break;
        case 89:
            text = '&#4637;';
            break;
        case 85:
            text = '&#4638;';
            break;
}
    
    if(text == 8){
        
        var str = document.getElementById("out").innerHTML;
        var foo = str.substring(0, str.length -1);
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = foo; 
    }else {
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += text;
    }

    }
    
</script>
<input  type='text'  onkeyup='check(event);' id='in' />
    
<div id='out' ></div>
```

Which changes only some of the `qwerty` letters to another unicodes as they get typed. meaning, each letter gets converted to another letter, but the problem is, there are some letters that can only be created with a combination of two key strokes, together or separately. i.e.

1. when you press <kbd>m</kbd> then quickly, <kbd>o</kbd> it should generate <kbd>x</kbd>;
2. or when you press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> it, it should generate <kbd>y</kbd>

The problem, here is that the code only recognized one letter per stroke. I tried using:

```
if(text == 77+79){  // this is for m + o
text 'x';
}
```

or even for the <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> which should output <kbd>z</kbd>.
I  the above argument it inside, but it is not working.

Comment: Already posted try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479307/how-can-i-detect-shift-key-down-in-javascript

Comment: Detecting a sequence of key presses (`m` is pressed and released, then `o` is pressed => `x`) would be different to detecting a key combination (`shift` + `p` simultaneously). How to do these two are very different questions. The latter seems already answered as @JDeveloper has pointed out; you should ask the former separately (it may already be answered too).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to capture "abnormal" key combos. And for that, I think you'll need to trap and record `keyup` *and* `keydown`.

You want something *like* this, but not necessarily this exactly ...

```
var keysdown = {};
var lastkey = 0;

element.onkeyup = function(evt) {
  var e = evt || window.event;
  keysdown[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode] = true;
}

element.onkeyup = function(evt) {
  var e = evt || window.event;
  var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
  keysdown[code] = false;
  switch (code) {
    // for cases wherein you need to detect keyA + keyB
    case 77:
      if (keysdown[79]) {
        // x
      } else {
        // m
      }
      break;
    // for cases wherein you need to detect sequence A, B
    case B:
       if (lastkey == A) {
         // do A,B
       } else {
         // do B
       }
       break;
  }
  lastkey = code;
}
```

Comment: @kranzdot I'll throw a fiddle together ... gimme a minute.

Comment: @kranzdot Quick question -- do you need to be able to detect sequences as well as combinations? Or, is my initial understanding correct, that 77 and 79 *together* produce 'x'?

Comment: That would be super awesome. Yes, you are right. But, not when pressed at the same time, just if 79 is pressed after 77.

Comment: don't worry to much about it

Comment: Sorry, I was out for a while. The code does not work, at all. I clicked on all letters in the keyboad, but nothing is showing up

Comment: @kranzdot You want the all original characters echoed to the textbox? ... just changed `return false;` to `return true;` in the `onkeyup` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?:

```
if(text == 77 && text == 79){
    text 'x';
}
```

Comment: I am not pressing two keys are the same time. Just one after the other. So, there is some timing involved

Answer (score 0):

In this example there are combinations with 2 keys like `ac` and `cd` but you could have 3 or more combinations like `agk`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        td {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //IE 8 and below doesn't have addEventLisener but all other majon browser have it
        if (Element.prototype.addEventListener === undefined) {
            Element.prototype.addEventListener = function (eventName, callback) {
                var me = this;
                this.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function () {
                    callback.call(me, window.event);
                });
            }
        }
        var myApp = {
            multiChar: [
                [65, 67],//ac
                [67, 68] //cd
            ],
            prefChar: [0, 0], //Index of mutichar match
            replacers: ["مرحبا", "وداعا"], //replace multichar matches (ac with مرحبا) 
            checkCode: function (e) {
                var i = 0, inp;
                //IE probably doesn't have shiftkey or implements it differently
                if (e.shiftKey) {
                    //check stuff with shift
                    console.log("with shift", e.keyCode);
                    //If a match found then reset prefChar
                    prefChar = [0, 0];
                    return;
                }
                for (i = 0; i < myApp.multiChar.length; i++) {
                    if (e.keyCode !== myApp.multiChar[i][myApp.prefChar[i]]) {
                        myApp.prefChar[i] = (e.keyCode === myApp.multiChar[i][0]) ? 1 : 0
                        continue
                    }
                    myApp.prefChar[i]++;
                    if (myApp.prefChar[i] === myApp.multiChar[i].length) {
                        // found a multichar match
                        console.log(myApp.replacers[i]);
                        inp = document.body.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
                        inp.value = inp.value.substr(
                            0, inp.value.length - myApp.multiChar[i].length) +
                            myApp.replacers[i];
                        myApp.prefChar[i] = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        document.body.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
            .addEventListener("keyup", myApp.checkCode);
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't replace anything at the moment just console.log a detection. Made a change to the code so for aaac the ac part will be detected as well.

Comment: new answer replaces it. it might be easier to use regexp instead of this though

Comment: Thank you so much, but the code seems very complex, can you direct me to a tutorial that helps me to record key presses?

Comment: It mostly relies on Arrays, multiChar contains an array of arrays so mutiChar[0] contains 2 values (the char codes for a and c or [65,67]. prefchar contains the indexes of the sub arrays in multiChar so if user typed a then prefChar is [1,0] bacause a matched keycode 65 in charCode[0][0] If I type c next it'll match charCode[0][1] (is 67). Work with multi dimentional arrays is a bit complicated and always hard to maintain or change later when you have to go back into the code and change it but it's a good fit for this particular problem.

Comment: the following is a good reference to javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: Hate to be picky but please consider making your answers shorter. The first 14 lines are totally useless.