# Check if Shift + letter is pressed in JS / Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way to check if Shift + letter is pressed in lodash's debounce?

```
fetchDebounced: _.debounce(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 16 && e.keyCode >= 46 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
    console.log('shift + letter is pressed')
  }
}
```

Doesn't work in my case, using it on `keyup` event. I want to print out console message, only when SHIFT+LETTER, for example, Shift+a is pressed (or Shift+z). Is it possible?

Comment: If it *always* "doesn't work", its an easy fix.  If not, can you explain when it "doesn't work"?

Comment: what listener you used, i forgot it, but there is specific way to add listeners to see if both buttons are pressed at same time.

Comment: This is a duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479307/how-can-i-detect-shift-key-down-in-javascript

Comment: Your condition fails because the `keyCode` can't be between 46-90 at the same time. Try using the `shiftKey` property instead of checking the shift keyCode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript

Comment: `e` (event object) has `.shiftKey` property (among many others).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect shift + key down in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479307/how-can-i-detect-shift-key-down-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use onkeydown and e.shiftKey:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode >= 46 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
    console.log("SHIFT + " + e.keyCode);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: My issues was with using `keyup` instead of `keydown` that's why my shiftKey was never true.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7479406/11384392):

> `event.shiftKey` is a boolean. `true` if the Shift key is being pressed, `false` if not. `altKey` and `ctrlKey` work the same way.
>
> So basically you just need to detect the keydown as normal with `onkeydown`, and check those properties as needed.

Comment: what is ```event``` in this example? ```console.log(event)``` outputs ```undefined``` for me

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using shiftkey press and keyCode check between 65-90(A-Z) on key up to track as one event

```js
function checkCode(e) {
    if(e.shiftKey){
    console.log(e.shiftKey && (e.keyCode >= 65 || e.keyCode <= 90))      
    }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup = "checkCode(event)" />
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NVqMOg

Answer (score 0):

Because people are answering, this is the best answer from [this previously-asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178431/how-to-catch-enter-keypress-on-textarea-but-not-shiftenter).

```
...onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
//      if (e.shiftKey === true)
        if (e.shiftKey)  // thruthy
        {
            // new line
        }
        else
        {
            // run your function
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also note [Das_Geek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029542/1447509)'s answer above, that `altKey` and `ctrlKey` work the same way, per the venerable [Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479307/how-can-i-detect-shift-key-down-in-javascript/7479406#7479406).