# Jquery set enter key textarea in My Code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an Jquery submit textarea, now I want to set textarea submit without button submit. Just using enter key.

```
<textarea id="ctextarea"></textarea>
```

Here it's the JS :

```
$('.comment_button').live("click",function() 
{
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var uid = $("#uid").val();
    var comment= $("#ctextarea"+ID).val();
    var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&msg_id=' + ID + '&uid=' + uid;

    if(comment=='')
    {
    $('#ctextarea').html("").fadeIn('slow');
    $("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
    }
    else if (!$.trim($("#ctextarea"+ID).val()))
    {
        $("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
    }
    else
    {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comment_ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("#commentload"+ID).append(html);
    $("#ctextarea"+ID).val('');
    $("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
     }
 });
}
return false;
});
```

I already search the tutorials and found, but I confused where can I put the code in My JS code.

Someone can give the idea ?
Thanks for helps.

Comment: I don't see any code here to monitor the `.keyup()` event.

Comment: Use the keypresssd  jquery function. Http://api.jquery.com/keypresssd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178431/how-to-catch-enter-keypress-on-textarea-but-not-shiftenter

Comment: I don't this will work... but if you find the right code place it in `$(document).ready`

Comment: Sorry wrong address http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#ctextarea').on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13){
        //enter key pressed.. 
    }
});
```

Comment: I already test, but not work, maybe you can give me a step where can I put that code ?

Comment: @Nagini [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVckk/) should outline everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to a keydown/keyup event and submit the form inside the event handler:

```
var KEY_ENTER = 13;
$('#ctextarea').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === KEY_ENTER) {
        $('form').submit();
        // Or perform any necessary ajax calls here
    }
});
```