# Javascript only when cursor focus within textbox

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to run a JavaScript function only when the cursor focus is in a specific textarea?

I want to perform an action on keypress of the `enter` key, however I don't want this event listner to be in place just generally on the page, rather only when the cursor is in the `textarea` I have (id is `postcontent`)

As an example, the function I'm using is this:

```
function onEnter(){
   if(characterCode == 13)
   {
       console.log("Enter pressed");
   }
}
```

Just as a start while I work out the focus issue...

I also have jQuery at my disposal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect pressing enter on keyboard using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178431/how-to-catch-enter-keypress-on-textarea-but-not-shiftenter

Comment: @George where does that question answer the issue of running only on focus of a specific text area?

Comment: You would just [attach the event handler to your textarea](http://jsfiddle.net/647vzpzn/) rather than the document. I.E: `$('textarea').keypress(..)` rather than `$(document).keypress(..)`.

Comment: `$('#postcontent').on('keypress', onEnter)`. I would try `keyup` instead.

Comment: And just so you know, you wouldn't be able to handle any `key` `event` in an element unless it's actually `focused`. So you can actually ignore the `focus` handling.

Answer (score 1):

```
div1.onfocus=
function onEnter(){
       if(characterCode == 13)
       {
           console.log("Enter pressed");
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("postcontent");

textArea.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress, false);

function handleKeyPress(e) {

    var characterCode = e.charCode;

    if (characterCode == 13) {
        console.log("Enter pressed");
    }

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/tnz0bhqd/)

Comment: ups, I just realized that maybe I misunderstood the question, if it was meant that the event should be focus on text area. I guess user3764857 got it right

Comment: Nope. You wouldn't be able to handle any `key` `event` in an element unless it's actually `focused`. You're right.